# Form/Survey embedded in a HTML5 Google Ad - possible?

Tags: html, google-ads-api, banner, banner-ads

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a form with working submit button to an HTML5 Ad e.g. in Google Adwords or if it is somehow restricted by Google/technology?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it' not possible. AdWords is not a survey tool, and is not thing for interaction. Its purpose is to advertise your ads to customers locally and globally, by specific targeting criteria, getting people to your website.

You may use AdWords for getting people landed to your survey form, and then to collect the statistics you need. Google AdWords will add you additional flexibility, with the tracking tools you'll get better insights of the survey form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It would have been cool for direct newsletter registration or similar, as well as improving engagement.

I take it from your answer it's not even possible to change the query string of a Link with javascript to match an input in an html5 banner.